# Use Google Calendar API to find next available time slot

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a function that will perform the following leveraging Google Calendar API:

- Find the next 30-minute calendar slot within a given parameter of days, start times, and end times
- Schedule a meeting for this task with supplied meeting info

I'm having a hard time finding good documentation for a process like this leveraging PHP / Javascript, and I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction or help me get the ball rolling.

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this is of interest https://kloudless.com/blog/2019/03/01/finding-a-time-to-meet-via-the-google-calendar-api/

Comment: You could do a [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#parameters) specifying timeMax and timeMin, and insert the events if the return is empty. Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking I can order by starttime and set maxResults to 1, and this should get me "next meeting", and then I can slot in prior to that. Just a lot of new concepts for me.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Calendar API has a `list` [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to return all events with a given calenarId (and optionally within a range of dates). Assuming that you have the OAuth of the user for the calendar that you want to access, use it to call the endpoint and the rest is writing a script to get the current time and comparing it with the calendar events to find the nearest 30-minute timeslot.

There is also an `insert` [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) for adding events.